# Meta NOINDEX tag not working

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layered-navigation, seo

I have applied this tag in my layout.xml to no index layered nav ( i have an ajax layered nav and also ive added rel=nofollow in the filter.phtml but i want to be sure)

Path- /app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout

```
 <layout>
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="head">
<action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</meta></action>
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
<reference name="head">
<action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</meta></action>
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered_nochildren>

    </layout>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the idea is to NOT index layered pages with FILTER = ACTIVE ... if this is the case I would update the question a little to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Path should be **app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/layout/local.xml**
If this is correct, make sure your cache is refreshed.

Is this really what you want to do? This will instruct robots to NOT INDEX all category pages that have layered navigation.

I would stick with nofollow on layered navigation links **OR** AJAX layered navigation as you mentioned, and keep your category pages indexed.